# Get the date variable in Fullcalendar.js and Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working to add datepicker to fullcalendar so users can skip to a desired date. The issue I am having is getting the date variable from datepicker to work with `calendar.gotoDate()`. I am sure this is something simple, but I only know enough about javascript to struggle by.

I currently have a script using datepicker like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    });

    function get_datepicker() {
        var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
        return date;
    };
});
```

After I call fullcalendar (which is working flawlessly) I am trying to add a listener for the date change.

```
document.getElementById('datepicker').addEventListener('change', function() {
        get_datepicker();
        calendar.gotoDate(date);
    });
```

since fullcalendar has removed jquery, it makes it a bit tougher (for me at least) to implement other scripts like datepicker, which normally wouldn't make sense to load, but in Wordpress, it is already there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never setting the `date` variable inside the change listener. Either of the following should work.

```
document.getElementById('datepicker').addEventListener('change', function() {
    let date = get_datepicker();
    calendar.gotoDate(date);
});
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('datepicker').addEventListener('change', function() {
    calendar.gotoDate(get_datepicker());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I was thinking because get_datepicker() returned a variable that I didn't need to set it again

Comment: When you return a variable, it returns the variable's value not the variable itself.